# How to eval a shell script to a Ruby hash?

Tags: ruby

I have this shell script in a file named a.sh:

```
export A='a'
export B=b
export C=1
export D=$USER  # say $USER is root
```

There are some other similar files b.sh, c.sh, etc.

I need to read the shell file, say a.sh, from ruby script and convert it to a Ruby hash:

```
{ 'A' => 'a', 'B' => 'b', 'C' => 1, 'D' => 'root' }
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: You have your environment variables in `ENV` constant.

Answer (score 3):

If you have run the bash script prior to the ruby one, you can get doing something like this:

```
Hash[([ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ] & ENV.keys).map {|x| [x, ENV[x]] }]
```

where array `[ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' ]` contains valid variable names to create the `Hash`.

If you need to parse the bash script in ruby, do as follows:

```
vars = {}
IO.read('shell.sh').each do| line |
   if line =~ /^export\s([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*)=\s*(?:['"]([^'"]*)['"]|(.*))\s*$/
      (name, value) = [ $1, $2 || $3 ]
      value.gsub!( /\$(?:([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z_0-9]*)|{([^{}]+)})/ ) do| match |
         ENV[ match[1..-1] ]
      end
      vars[ name ] = value.gsub(/#.*/, '').strip
   end
end
vars
# => {"A"=>"a", "B"=>"b", "C"=>"1", "D"=>"malo"}
```

Comment: Sorry, I might not state clearly. The shell script is not executed prior to ruby script, I need to read the shell script in ruby script. So ENV doesn't contain those variables yet.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ: I know, tag markup is fun, but please don't :)

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Thanks for your answer. But that's still not what I want. Because shell.sh might be a real shell script, so I have to use shell to interpret it then get result from environment.

Comment: @EvanLi please be decided no will you run the script before, or not.